# Install apk over 250mb from another application

Tags: java, android, actionscript-3, air, apk

**Problem**

I'm using the following java code to simple call the installation dialog with stored locally on sd card apk file:

```
             Intent intent = new Intent();
             intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
             intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + args[0].getAsString()), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

             context.getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

And everything is going to be fine when i'm using apk files < 250mb in other case application would crash.
The problem is that i **totally need** every single part of this >250mb apk and there is no way to split it by extension packs. So is there any workaround about this limitation?

**Manifest**

```
<android>
    <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[<manifest android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="false" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />
    <application android:debuggable="true"/>
    <application>
        <activity android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-feature android:required="true" android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" />
</manifest>]]></manifestAdditions>
  </android>
```

**Also**

Maybe you need to know that my application is written by AS3 with Adobe Air and using this java code as native extension to execute apk files. But be sure that it isn't necessary and you will face the same problem using pure java application.

Comment: You should be getting and error on crash. What it say?

Answer (score 0):

Each Android-powered device has a different amount of RAM available to the system and thus provides a different heap limit for each app. You can call getMemoryClass() to get an estimate of your app's available heap in megabytes. If your app tries to allocate more memory than is available here, it will receive an OutOfMemoryError.

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html